# Send a custom token on mainnet using phantom @solana/web3.js

Tags: javascript, token, solana, solana-web3js

I'm currently trying to dev a website allowing people to buy things that are available on the web site by using tokens from our project.  (so it's just about sending tokens, not a trade between tokens and a NFT).
I've done almost everything needed, and everything works using SOL. Now i want to switch the payements to our own custom token.

I've digged every posts on this forum and tried all of them but still couldn't find something working for me.

The problem is that all those answers use a hardcoded private key or the Wallet Interface which requires a Signer (keypair). Since our users will log on the site thanks to phantom it's not possible for us to get that secret key. Have you got any idea on how to implement that custom token payement?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the solana wallet adapter https://github.com/solana-labs/wallet-adapter you can use the wallet object to sign your transactions. They have an example in the readme to transfer SOL, transferring an spl-token is very similar, i often use https://github.com/solstar-tech/easy-spl which works well together with the adapter.